# What are the dimensions of a SSD with x inch?

Tags: ssd, dimensions

I've measured that my OCZ Vertex 2 SATA II SSD has a diagonal of 17 cm. The Google calculator says that [17 cm is 6.69 inch](http://www.google.com/search?q=17+cm+in+inch), not even near to 2.5 or 1.8 inch. The [OCZ product page](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-vertex-2-sata-ii-2-5-ssd.html) says that the drive is 2.5 inch.

Am I doing it the right way by measuring the diagonal? Or should I take the width? [7 cm is 2.76 inch](http://www.google.com/search?q=7+cm+in+inch), but [2.5 inch is 6.35 cm](http://www.google.com/search?q=2.5+inch+in+cm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension refers to the diameter of the platter within a drive. Obviously, there is no such thing within an SSD, but the size is quoted as the form factor of the casing of the SSD drive is made to match those of traditional drive so that they can be easily used in place of a traditional one.

The actual width of the casing of a 2.5" drive is 2.75". The depth varies.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the standard sizes are 2.5 and 3.5 inches, which means the width. The height is standardized and the 3rd dimension is unimportant. Look at a typical PC having a couple of 2.5 and 3.5 inch wide slots (there are also 5.25 wide slots intended for CD/DVD mechanics).

Comment: Height is NOT standardized - there are 7.5mm and 9mm SSDs, just like 2.5" laptop hard drives!

Answer (score 0):

No. You do not measure the diagonal. Measure the width of the connector side and that should match up.

Answer (score 0):

I measure the hard disk of my old notebook, it is 4" x 3.5", when checking in the market, there is only 2 type of hard disk, i.e. 2.5" & 3.5". 2.5" is meant for notebook & 3.5" is meant for desktop. This explains that the measurement of hard disk is not by its physical casing measurement but the disk plate inside the hard disk.

Comment: This answer has already been given in the accepted answer. Please avoid posting duplicate answers that do not add any more helpful information.